# Callback event subscription

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, callback

I have a WorkManager class with a AddWork() method and a WorkDone event. 
Other components of the system will call WorkManager.AddWork() and should only be notified when their work has completed. Instead of the event notifying every client when every event fires.

I'm struggling to find an elegant solution.

Thanks all!

EDIT:
Another way to look at this is, say I have a class called JobManager with an event called OnWorkDone().
I have 2 other classes that need to listen to this event.

Event subscriber class 1

```
WorkManager.OnWorkDone += WorkDoneJob1;
void WorkDoneJob1()
{
     print("Job 1 is done!");
}
```

Event subscriber class 2

```
WorkManager.OnWorkDone += WorkDoneJob2;
void WorkDoneJob2()
{
     print("Job 2 is done!");
}
```

In this model if the jobmanager completes job1 it will print "job 1 done" and "job 2 done" since all clients get notified that event fired.

I only want class1 to get a notification when it's job has completed.

Comment: Can you post your current code so that we can have a look?

Comment: It's a ton of code so I attempted to simplify it above.

Comment: updated with some pseudo

Comment: This isn't going to work in a web application unless you go out of your way to make sure these objects still exist. Once the request is done, the page is gone, and can't be accessed.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned more of the details before.

Comment: We're using the Quartz framework for a threaded concurrent "jobs" framework.

The current workflow we're creating is being developed in 3 vertical slices. 
My slice is supposed to get a request for "work" (without going into industry specific details) which might take several hours to complete(has to call a lot of vendor APIs, etc). I have a WorkManager() that will create the "jobs". So when workflow step #2 is done with it's work, it passing in work for my component.

Once the job has completed it will notify the manager that keeps track of the jobs that it's done.

Comment: The workmanager and/or job should then be able to notify to requester that the work is done without them having to poll constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the event on the job object you add to the manager and subscribe to it before you AddWork() it to the manager. Alternatively make the manager accept a callback with the addwork method and have a dictionary of jobs and callbacks which the manager fires when the jobs done.

Comment: Hmm. So pass in a delegate as a param to the AddWork() call, then the WorkManager can spin up the job and attach the clients delegate and it's own.

When the job fires the event, the manager and client would be notified? 

I'm liking this idea!!!

Would you mid providing a code example about passing in a delegate and attaching it to an eventhandler etc?

Thanks

Comment: Passing in a callback is the way to go! Thanks Jimmy and everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

Change your OnWorkDone delegate to include an event args type, which could include an identifier for the job completed, then your handler can check if it cares about the event or not.

```
public delegate void OnWorkDone(object jobIdentifer);

void WorkDoneJob1(object jobIdentifer)
{
  if (jobIdentifer == this.jobIdentifer)
  {
     print("Job 1 is done!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use events.  Just call the class's Complete method.

I don't usually write C# so my syntax may be out.

```
class WorkManager {
    void DoWord {
        WorkTask task = GetNextWorkTask();
        PerformWork(task);
        task.Complete();
    }

    WorkTask GetNextWorkTask() { ... }

    void PerformWork(WorkTask task) { ... }
}

virtual class WorkTask {
    virtual void Complete;
}

class WorkTask1 : WorkTask {
    void Complete {
        print("Job 1 done.");
    }
}
```